# Child resource shown again in fully developed relationship EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have fully developed 1-many relationship in EF Core between Universitiy and Major.

I need to show a University A with its Majors, but those Majors have a reference to University A and A is shown as "JSON children" every time and i would like it not to be shown.

Is there any way to deal with this?
If someone needs more heres the repo: https://github.com/nambonumestinvisibili/SGrade/tree/master/SGrade

Major

```
public class Major : IGradable
    {
        public University University { get; set; }
        public int UniversityId {get;set;}
        public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

Major DTO: (Mapping is made with automapper)

```
public class MajorDTO : Major
    {
        public string Type { get; set; } = "Major";
    }
```

University

```
public class University : IGradable
    {
        public ICollection<Major> Majors { get; set; }

    }
```

Uni repo

```
public class UniversityRepo : GradableRepo<University>, IUniversityRepo
    {
        public UniversityRepo(SGradeContext sgcontext) : base(sgcontext)
        {

        }

        public async Task<University> GetPresentingUniversity(int id)
        {
            IQueryable<University> query = _context.Universities
                //.Include(x => x.Reviews)
                //.Include(x => x.Subjects.Take(5))
                //.Include(x => x.Teachers.Take(5))
                .Include(x => x.Majors);

            return await query.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
    }
```

part of controller:

```
// GET: api/Universities/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<University>> GetUniversity(int id)
        {
            var university = await _repo.GetPresentingUniversity(id);

            if (university == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return _mapper.Map<University, UniversityDTO>(university);
        }
```

Response:

```
{
    "type": "University",          //this is university A
    "majors": [
        {
            "university": {        //and here it is repeated
                "majors": [],
                "name": "Uniwersytet Wrocławski",
                "starsRating": 2.5,
                "reviews": null,
                "isConfirmed": true,
                "votes": 0,
                "id": 3
            },
            "universityId": 3,
            "subjects": null,
            "teachers": null,
            "users": null,
            "name": "Informatyka",
            "starsRating": 2.5,
            "reviews": null,
            "isConfirmed": true,
            "votes": 0,
            "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "name": "Uniwersytet Wrocławski",
    "starsRating": 2.5,
    "reviews": [],
    "isConfirmed": true,
    "votes": 0,
    "id": 3
}
```

Comment: leaving for visiters:
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when serializing 1-to-many relationships and this did a trick:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 0;
            });
     }
```

Check if it works for you.
Here is a demo project with all types of relationships in EF Core 5, where I had this problem.
https://github.com/mikuam/PrimeHotel/commit/ef47a9faeb8111e363adb921287ac9392cd50e97

However, I must admit that exposing Model classed in controllers is not ideal and having Dtos, where you expose only what you should is way better. What's more, you can control how deep you resolve relationships.